# Adding JS dependencies to pure HTML 5 project with minimum recompilations / processing

Tags: javascript, npm

Suppose I have `.html` / `.css` / `.js` files and serve them as static resources  via any WEB server.

There is comprehensive NPM repository of JS packages.

I wonder what is the way I can package (in another words download and extract with defined layout) those libraries so I can reference them from `<script src=""></script>` from `.html` files?

So I am looking for convenient way of grabbing dependencies (jQuery, React, React-Redux, etc) from Internet with NPM and making them available for learning JS libraries without any magic from transpillers, minifiers, enhansers, ES 20xx polyfils. Just plain old JS files as it was in old days...

Let say after describing dependency `jquery:3.3.1` I expect to see `jquery.min.js` inside `public/jslibs` or similar location, not somewhere inside `node_modules`...

**UPDATE** I know https://www.webjars.org/ that makes what I ask but for Java project. They unfortunately repackage all OSS libraries in their own Maven repository....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's (still experimental) functionality of `unpkg.com` service that allows to import npm packages as modules.

A cool package called [htm](https://github.com/developit/htm#usage) recently showed up that allows to use jsx-like syntax in a browser without any transpilers.

```html
<script type="module">
import * as R from 'https://unpkg.com/ramda?module';

const result = R.map(R.inc, [1, 2, 3])
console.log(result)
</script>
```

Comment: `unpkg.com` is awesome. It looks like project repackaged NPM repository. So there is no way to make something like that with only NPM without their CDN...

Comment: @gavenkoa to access a npm package you need to have a url to it so it needs to be hosted somewhere. Currently company behind npm doesn't support web imports and also most modules are not ready to be imported in this way but this is the future.

Answer (score 0):

https://bower.io/ says

> Web sites are made of lots of things — frameworks, libraries, assets, and utilities. Bower manages all these things for you.

But during `npm install -g bower` I saw warning:

> npm WARN deprecated bower@1.8.4: We don't recommend using Bower
>   for new projects. Please consider Yarn and Webpack or Parcel. You
>   can read how to migrate legacy project here: https://bower.io/blog/2017/how-to-migrate-away-from-bower/